# How to use a validation between two datepicker?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker, material-design-in-xaml

Suppose I have two `DatePicker`, I want that the first `DatePicker` date must be less to the second `DatePicker`. The date of the second `DatePicker` must be greather then the first.

If the first `DatePicker` have a date greather than the second, then a validation error should appear on the datepicker.

These are my `DatePickers`:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="StartPeriod"
            SelectedDate="{Binding PeriodStartDate}">
</DatePicker>

<DatePicker x:Name="EndPeriod"
            SelectedDate="{Binding PeriodEndDate}">
</DatePicker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface in your view model:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _validationErrors = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    private DateTime _periodStartDate;
    public DateTime PeriodStartDate
    {
        get { return _periodStartDate; }
        set { _periodStartDate = value; Validate(); }
    }

    private DateTime _periodEndDate;
    public DateTime PeriodEndDate
    {
        get { return _periodEndDate; }
        set { _periodEndDate = value; Validate(); }
    }

    private void Validate()
    {
        if (_periodStartDate > _periodEndDate)
            _validationErrors.Add(nameof(PeriodStartDate), $"{nameof(PeriodEndDate)} cannot be smaller than {nameof(PeriodStartDate)}");
        else
            _validationErrors.Clear();

        RaiseErrorsChanged(nameof(PeriodStartDate));
    }

    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;
    private void RaiseErrorsChanged(string propertyName) =>
        ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    public bool HasErrors => _validationErrors.Count > 0;

    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
    {
        string error;
        if (_validationErrors.TryGetValue(propertyName, out error))
            return new string[1] { error };

        return null;
    }
}
```

Please refer to [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx) article for more information.