# WPF get HasError of a binding from source property

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, binding

Given a TextBox with straight forward binding and validation:

```
<TextBox Content="{Binding ProblematicText}" ValidationRule="...">
```

And the source property in my DataContext:

```
public string ProblematicText
{
    // ...
}
```

In code i have to use the value of the property 'ProblematicText' unless the TextBox has an error in its ValidationRule.

How can I access the `BindingExpression.HasError` from code or achieve this simply?

Comment: ps: I obviously don't have a way to use `BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(dependencyObject, dependencyProperty);` because those are 'unknown'.

Comment: I am accessing various properties this way. I bind the properties in XAML (View), but in C# (ViewModel) I am not aware of what gui element stands behind which property.

Comment: You should handle the validation logic in the view model. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view model doesn't know (and it's certainly not supposed to either) anything about any validation rules that may be defined in the view. So if `ProblematicText` is defined in a view model, you should perform the validation in this class.

Get rid of the validation rule and implement the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface in your view model. Below are some links that should give the idea.

**WPF 4.5: Validating Data in Using the INotifyDataErrorInfo Interface:** https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.wpf-4-5-validating-data-in-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx

[How to use a validation between two datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52006436/how-to-use-a-validation-between-two-datepicker/52006845#52006845)